# UIButton with Constraints showing Center (500,500)

Tags: ios, uibutton, constraints, coordinates, uistoryboard

I created a UIButton in Storyboard with some constraints, linked it to a class, when I try to print the button's center coordinates it prints (500.0,500.0) no matter where the button is positioned. Can somebody explain why this is happening (I'm pretty sure its because of the constraints but I don't have an explanation for it).

Comment: Can you show us the constraints? Screenshot the list in the Size Inspector for your UIButton

Comment: Where are you printing the center? If it's before the view has gotten it's initial layout pass then it's meaningless.

Comment: Are you using `frame` (relative to the superview) or `bounds` (relative to itself)?

Comment: @dan The first thing I was doing was printing the center in viewDidLoad. I believe you're right, I added another button that when pressed printed the first button's center and it printed the correct coordinates. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!

Comment: @dan For some more insight, where would you suggest placing this print statement for the button's center? For example, if the first and only thing I want my program to do is print the button's center automatically when it runs. Rather than viewDidLoad, maybe viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the print statement in viewDidLayoutSubviewMethod. In this method it is confirmed that all the views are laid out.

Since in viewDidLoad the views are not laid out, therefore you are getting incorrect output.

Visit the apple reference if you need more clarity on this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews

Comment: Alternatively, if he really wants to have the button layout calculated there, he could use the `layoutIfNeeded` method to force the inmediate layout.

Comment: I think that will be overkill :P

Comment: it's easier actually, since `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called several times and `viewDidLoad` only once, but that's up to the programmer.